# Shapefile not aligning with raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, google-earth-engine

When I upload a raster and shapefile into Google Earth Engine, the shapefile doesn't align properly.

The datasets align perfectly in ArcMap, ENVI and R.

Both the raster and the shapefile are in EPSG 4326. The problem appears to be with the shapefile, as the raster lines up well with the GEE base map.

Can anyone provide insight as to how to fix this issue?

[image: Offset shapefile in Google Earth Engine]

[image: Correctly aligned shapefile in ArcMap]

```
var cityWGS = image.select('b1', 'b2', 'b3');
Map.addLayer(cityWGS, {min: 0, max: 256}, 'CityWGS');

var test = ee.FeatureCollection('users/..../TestGR');
test = test.geometry();
Map.addLayer(test, {color: 'red'}, 'Green Roofs');

print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', cityWGS.projection());
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', test.projection());
```

[image: GEE projection info for raster and shapefile]

Comment: Could you maybe show the ogrinfo and gdalinfo of the tif and shp?

Answer (score -1):

As a work-around, you could try converting the Shapefile to another format (e.g. CSV, KML) with QGIS/R/..., then import it again to GEE and see whether this changes anything. If this does not work, at least you'll know that it's not because of the Shapefile format as such!